# Prompt error status RAILS - API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have basically this:

```
class Api::NameController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
    def index

    end

    def create
        begin
            cou = params[:data].count
        rescue
         render status: 422, json: {
            message: "Error Loading data- Check your data",
            }.to_json
         end

        input = params[:data]

        # Operations with the input data

        render status: 200, json: {
            message: "Succesful data calculation",
            data_output: input
            }.to_json

    end

end
```

The data is: `{"data":[1,34,5]}`

I would like to render the status error 422, when the data has a bad sintax (example: `{"dat":[1,34,5]}` or `{"data":1,34,5]}` etc)

With the example above doe not work. When sending via `cURL {"data":1,34,5]}` I got:

```
Started POST "/api/energy" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-29 08:35:50 +0200
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

{"data":1,5,67]}

ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (795: unexpected token at '{"data":1,5,67]}'):
```

When sending `{"dat":[1,34,5]}` I got

```
Processing by Api::EnergyController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"dat"=>[1, 5, 67], "energy"=>{"dat"=>[1, 5, 67]}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):
```

Could anyone help me putting this error status in the correct form?

Comment: use render and return. So it will not throw double render error. It will return from the resuce block.

Comment: it definetely works, but how to handle ParseError in my case. I have tried somethings but without success